# Is there any Maven plugins available to to remove getter/setters of generated classes from Jhipster and add lombok

Tags: java, maven, jhipster, maven-plugin

The jhipster generated domain classes have a lot of getters/setters. Why isn't it integrated with lombok?
Is there any maven plugin available to migrate the generated classes to lombok style ?
I am not looking at IDE plugins that migrate . I am looking for any maven plugin that does this kind of migration.

Comment: My requirement is , we are generating the basic scaffold of the project using a tool which uses internally jhipster. After the scaffold created, if we observe, any files ,DTOs generated with getters and setters .To remove this boilerplate code and add lombok , is there any maven plugin available to get rid of this getter setters and migrate the code to lombok in one shot.I got few answers like we have option in IDEs (intellij) to do this refactor. But I am looking for a generic solution instead of depending on IDE.

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't believe any IDE plugins exist for this. You'd have to do it manually.

We've had requests in the past for Lombok. We don't use it because it causes too many issues. See these GitHub issues for more information.

- https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/398
- https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/5997